# excel vba: using string to set slicer doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set the slicer for a pivot table based on values I collected earlier in a string.

The code below works:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Merk1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
"[dXref].[Merk].&[J17]", "[dXref].[Merk].&[J18]")
```

However, instead of having two values like J17 and J18, I could have an unknown amount of them. So the code could also be:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Merk1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
"[dXref].[Merk].&[J17]", "[dXref].[Merk].&[J18]", "[dXref].[Merk].&[J50]", "[dXref].[Merk].&[J500]")
```

To solve this, in earlier code I collect whatever values I want to filter and I put them together in a string called "txt".

So the string "txt" could contain this:

```
"[dXref].[Merk].&[J17]", "[dXref].[Merk].&[J18]"
```

or

```
"[dXref].[Merk].&[J17]", "[dXref].[Merk].&[J18]", "[dXref].[Merk].&[J50]", "[dXref].[Merk].&[J500]"
```

Then I assumed this would work:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Merk1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
txt)
```

I thought that replacing the code that normally works to set the slicer with a variable containing the same code would work. However I keep getting error messages that give a clue that there is something wrong with the comma in the txt string when setting the slicer. 
I have been searching online for hours and trying endless things. I might be missing something simple.... can someone figure this out? Thanks a lot.

The full sub below (which is now working):

```
Sub FiltersMatchen()
    Dim Selectie As Range
    Dim FilterArray() As String
    Dim FilterString As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Merk As Range
    Dim FiltercodeBegin As String
    Dim FiltercodeEinde As String

    Set Selectie = Selection

    i = 0
    ReDim FilterArray(0)
    For Each Merk In Selectie
        FilterArray(i) = Merk
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve FilterArray(i)
    Next

    FiltercodeBegin = "[dXref].[Merk].&["
    FiltercodeEinde = "]"

    For i = LBound(FilterArray) To UBound(FilterArray) - 1
        FilterString = FilterString & FiltercodeBegin & FilterArray(i) & FiltercodeEinde & Chr(44)
    Next i

    FilterString = Left(FilterString, Len(FilterString) - 1)

    FilterArray = Split(FilterString, ",")

    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Merk1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = FilterArray
End Sub
```

Comment: Array(txt) will give an array with only one string, the contents of txt. Use Split to create an array from a string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vincent, I actually tried that, but couldn't get it to work. Could you show how? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not testing this on your data but creating an Array using split should work like so: Array = Split(txt ",")

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Merk1").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array = Split(txt ",") 
gives me a compile error, missing: (

Comment: I added the full sub to my post, so you guys have more of an idea what I'm doing.. but it still isn't working..

Comment: Ok I found the solution, see my edit above. I didn't have to include the "" "" inside the array items. Stupid of me...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I had to split the string into an array, and the individual items in the array don't need to have the " " characters around them while preparing those items. I assumed they were required because if you manually fill in the array (what you see when you record the a macro) they are there.

So, manually an array item looks like this:
"[dXref].[Merk].&[J17]"

Using an array, an item looks like this:
[dXref].[Merk].&[J17

I edited the start post with the solution. The sub is used to apply a selection of the pivot table to the slicer connected to that pivot table.